issue when installing npm
`PS C:\Users\Dell\Documents\GitHub\Project> npm install
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "^n8.3.3" of package "@types/react@^n8.3.3": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-08-01T09_03_38_648Z-debug-0.log`
i tried depoying the website but couldnt because of the same issue:
Diagnosis: The build failure is due to an invalid tag name error during the npm installation process.
Solution: The npm error "EINVALIDTAGNAME" is caused by an invalid character in the package tag name. In this case, the tag "^n8.3.3" for the package "@types/react@^n8.3.3" is invalid. To resolve this, the tag name should be corrected to a valid format, typically starting with a number. Update the dependency declaration for "@types/react" to use a valid tag name, for example, "^8.3.3", and ensure that it follows the semantic versioning standards.

delete node_modules & Clean Cache , it's worked for me .
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean --force
npm I

